# Hive Runtime error while inserting geospatial data into a partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive, gis, esri, partition

I am having a problem while loading data into a partitioned table

1) I want to load data from an existing table enodeb into a partitioned table enodebpartition. The schema for enode b is

```
-state                   string                  
-circle                  string                  
-businessranking         string                 
-enodebstatus            string                  
-shape                   binary
```

2) I created the following partitioned table enodebpartition as shown

```
create table enodebpartition (circle string, businessranking string,
enodebstatus string, shape binary)partitioned by (state string)   
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.esri.json.hadoop.UnenclosedJsonInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

3) Then I loaded the data into the table from he already existing enodeb table

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
insert overwrite table enodebpartition partition (state) select * from  
enodeb;
```

4) However I am getting the following error

```
Diagnostic Messages
for this Task: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error
while processing row {
    "state": "Punjab",
    "circle": "PUNJAB",
    "businessranking": "2",
    "enodebstatus": "SCFT Samsung Acceptance Initiated",
    "shape": ף0Kc#������ IA
}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java: 172) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java: 54) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java: 453) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java: 343) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java: 168) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java: 422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java: 1657) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java: 162) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error
while processing row {
    "state": "Punjab",
    "circle": "PUNJAB",
    "businessranking": "2",
    "enodebstatus": "SCFT Samsung Acceptance Initiated",
    "shape": ף0Kc#������ IA
}
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java: 545) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java: 163)...8 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.SubStructObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardStructObjectInspector at com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde.serialize(Unknown Source) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java: 712) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java: 838) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java: 88) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java: 838) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java: 97) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java: 164) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java: 535)...9 more FAILED: Execution Error,
    return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask MapReduce Jobs Launched: Stage - Stage - 1: Map: 5 HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

5) In short I am getting an error as

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.SubStructObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardStructObjectInspector
```

I need help as I am not able to comprehend this error. 
Kindly help me out with this issue

Thanks

Comment: Might be a bug in the Esri JSON SerDe.  You might file an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/issues), with a link to the full stack trace in a Gist.  [collaborator]

Comment: Thanks @RandallWhitman. i have raised an issue just now.